# GLFW unable to get OpenGL 4.1 context on Mavericks

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glew, glfw

I am trying to get an OpenGL context above version 2 on mac using GLFW. My configuration is Mavericks (10.9.1) + XCode and I have an Nvidia Geforce 650M GPU with OpenGL 4.1 Full Profile potentially supported. I use the following code:

```
    static void test_error_cb (int error, const char *description)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", error, description);
}
```

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

```
glfwSetErrorCallback(test_error_cb);

// Initialise GLFW
if (!glfwInit())
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


//Request Specific Version
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// Open OpenGL window
window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Split view demo", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n");

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Set callback functions
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebufferSizeFun);
glfwSetWindowRefreshCallback(window, windowRefreshFun);
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, cursorPosFun);
glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseButtonFun);
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

// Enable vsync
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glfwSwapInterval(1);

glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
framebufferSizeFun(window, width, height);

//Check Version
int major, minor, rev;
major = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR);
minor = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR);
rev = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_REVISION);
printf("OpenGL version recieved: %d.%d.%d\n", major, minor, rev);
printf("Supported OpenGL is %s\n", (const char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION));
printf("Supported GLSL is %s\n", (const char*)glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));


// Main loop
for (;;)
{
    // Only redraw if we need to
    if (do_redraw)
    {
        // Draw all views
        drawAllViews();

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        do_redraw = 0;
    }

    // Wait for new events
    glfwWaitEvents();

    // Check if the window should be closed
    if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        break;
}

// Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
glfwTerminate();

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Currently glfwCreateWindow function fails. Without any hints (i.e. no glfwWindowHint calls) I can only have OpenGL 2.1 with glsl version at 1.20. Advise.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if you can get a 3.3 context rather than 3.2.

Comment: Changed the code now to return errors. Now it compiles and creates a 4.1 ogl context however the output screen is blank!

Answer (score 1):

A Core context is required to access GL versions greater than 2.1 on OSX.

Uncomment your `GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE` hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before your `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` and uncomment your profile hint.

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB
```

Comment: Now it compiles but still with Core Profile hint but still unable to open the window!

Comment: Ok It compiles and outputs the correct version number but the screen is blank:
 ./Split\ View 
OpenGL version recieved: 4.1.0
Supported OpenGL is 4.1 NVIDIA-8.18.22 310.40.05f01
Supported GLSL is 4.10

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're disabling the core profile hint. I don't have an answer, but you *might* get some more information via the error callback, e.g.,

```
extern "C"
{
    static void test_error_cb (int error, const char *description)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", error, description);
    }
}

...

{
    glfwSetErrorCallback(test_error_cb);

    if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE)
    {
        ....
```

This is a function that can be used prior to `glfwInit`.